# Difference between Navigating one fragment to another using fragment id and action id using nav graph in android jetpack library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, navgraph

I am using jetpack navigation graph in my android project. Normally to navigate one to another fragment we connect a link between them in nav graph and call like this

```
 findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_navigation_login_to_navigation_send_code)
```

But We can call the fragment this way as well without creating the link.

```
 findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigation_send_code)
```

What is the basic difference? In my sense, both do the same work.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions back to the same `navController` [navigate() function](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/422a6ae/navigation/navigation-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/NavController.java#770)  that takes in an integer resource id whether it's a fragment id or an action id.

> Navigate to a destination from the current navigation graph. This supports both navigating
> via an {@link NavDestination#getAction(int) action} and directly navigating to a destination.

Internally it calls [this navigate() version](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/422a6ae/navigation/navigation-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/NavController.java#807) where it examines whether it's an action id or not.

If it's an action id, then it gets the destination id from it; if not an action id it consider it as a destination id and continue on; notice the comments in below:

```
@IdRes int destId = resId;
final NavAction navAction = currentNode.getAction(resId);
Bundle combinedArgs = null;
if (navAction != null) { // here the destId is an action id
    if (navOptions == null) {
        navOptions = navAction.getNavOptions();
    }
    destId = navAction.getDestinationId(); // resets the destId to the destination id
    Bundle navActionArgs = navAction.getDefaultArguments();
    if (navActionArgs != null) {
        combinedArgs = new Bundle();
        combinedArgs.putAll(navActionArgs);
    }
}

// Now destId is the destination fragment id.. continue on...
```

So, technically no difference, but adding an action id adds an extra step of getting the fragment id which is nothing in terms of scalable apps.

The other difference, that if you put an actionId instead of a fragment id, you'd have an extra feature of `navOptions` that can be returned from the navGraph like adding enter/exit animation.

Comment: You'd check the [`NavOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavOptions) class to see the other features beside the animation

Comment: yes, using action id we get an extra feature nav options, but it can achieve programmatically

Comment: You're right; usually they tend to have the thing done by XML to do it programmatically to cover most of the situations and use cases that developers can encounter; some developers like to have those stuff on XML and not to jam the behavior code with such animations; others don't like that. it's at your preference

Comment: If you don't have navOptions, you'd go ahead directly with the destination id; the action id also can have a feature that indicates the source and destination; in case it's taken into consideration, so making it more readable programmatically (which source and which destination)